# Dynamic buttons href tests with phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm initiating my tests using phpunit so, I have doubts about how to test things dynamically. I created a table dynamically as the image bellow

Here are my view:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                @if(Session::has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
                @endif
                <table class="table">
                    <th>Unity Name</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($companies as $company)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$company->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$company->owner_number}}</td>
                                <td>
                                <a href="/admin/company/{{$company->id}}" class="btn btn-default fa fa-newspaper-o"></a>
                                <a href="/admin/company/{{$company->id}}/clients" class="btn btn-default fa fa-users"></a>
                                <a href="company/{{$company->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default fa fa-pencil-square-o"></a>
                                {{Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'url'=>'/admin/company/'.$company->id, 'style' => 'display:inline'])}}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default fa fa-trash-o"></button>
                                {{Form::close()}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So, how can I test the href tag if I haven't previously the tag id?

Comment: Please, try to paste your code here instead of adding an image of it.

Comment: Sorry my later reply, so there are my view where I'm generating my table

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests like these one in Symfony projects.

In dev environment, I insert some data in a dev database. After this step, I launch functionnal tests. In these tests, I analyze tag's content. Here is an example from your data :

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/yourUrl');
$node = $crawler->filter('#show-company-1');
self::assertNotEmpty($node, "Node #show-company-1 does not exists");
self::assertEmpty( $node->html(), "#show-company-1 content is not empty");
self::assertContains('/admin/company/1', $node->attr('href'), "a#show-company-1.href has not a good value");
```

Before request, you can add some logic to determine the id of your company.

Comment: At first Thanks for your reply! I thought about it because in my machine test I always could have the company number one in database as my example but if I haven't ? I'm just asking and thinking in this possibility and if it's a good pattern.